# Angular 8 - Shared component being called twice on other component calling it

Tags: angular, typescript

So I have a dialog component and its parent sharing a reusable component. Every time I call a function of the reusable component from the dialog, it also calls it from its parents (both are calling the function on ngAfterViewInit()) Any idea how to prevent the parent from calling it twice?

Parent Component

```
@ViewChild('receivablesCustomerAcc', {static: false}) private customerAccountSelect: CustomerAccountSelectComponent;

public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.customerAccountSelect.getCustomerAccounts();
}
```

Dialog Component

```
@ViewChild('addReceivableCustomerAcc', {static: false}) private dialogcustomerAccountSelect: CustomerAccountSelectComponent;

private ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.dialogcustomerAccountSelect.getCustomerAccounts();
}
```

Shared Component

```
export class CustomerAccountSelectComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    constructor(
        private customerService: CustomerApiService,
    ) { }

    public ngOnInit(): void {

    }

    public getCustomerAccounts() {
        // Retrieves data from API
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be best if you could share some code, and preferably a stackblitz example reproducing your issue

Comment: @PoulKruijt hi. edited my question to include some part of the code

Comment: Is this the exact code, or do you subscribe to a pipe both places? That could explain why the parent also receives the data.

Comment: @AndreasEngedal yes this is the exact code

Comment: `It gets called from its parent` because you have code in `ngAfterViewInit` in parent as well as child. so it will get called twice. Put code in either one of them. Also its very much difficult to answer it, without knowing what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the function on the dialog, you could pass the content of the getCustomerAccounts() from the parent to the dialog. You can either to this using localstorage/sessionstorage or pass it to the dialog, when opening it.
Angular material Dialog, has a data property which can be used to send data to the dialog.
It could look like this:

```
 dialogRef = this.matDialog
        .open(SomeDialog, {
          data: { someData}
        })
```

The data can then be retrieved using:

```
 constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public dialogData,
  ) { }
  ngOnInit() {

    const someData = this.dialogData.someData;

  }
```

Hope that helped. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb regarding dialogs (according to me) is:

1. For everything you need inside the dialog, fetch it in the caller component and pass it as dialog data.
2. All dialog actions should output event to parent component which is responsible for actual business logic.

Second rule does not apply to dialog which are self sufficient (sharing exactly the same logic between multiple components)